# how to check all the checkbox with two different class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to check/uncheck all of the checkboxes, in such way that if one of the checkboxes is checked/unchecked, all will be checked/unchecked.

Here is my code:

HTML :

```
<th><input type="checkbox" name="pay" id="chkAll"  class="chkAll"/>With Pay</th>
<th><input type="checkbox" name="pay" id="chkAll2" class="chkAll2"/>Without Pay</th>    


<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay" value="With Pay" class="chk" id="chk"/></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pay" value="Without Pay" class="chk2"  id="chk2"/></td>
```

JS:

```
 $('.chkAll').change(function () {
     var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("check_", "");
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(".chk").prop('checked', true);
         $(".chk2").prop('checked', false);
         $('.chkAll2').prop('checked', false);
     } else {
         $(".chk").prop('checked', false);
     }
 });

 $('.chkAll2').change(function () {
     var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("check_", "");
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(".chk2").prop('checked', true);
         $(".chk").prop('checked', false);
         $('.chkAll').prop('checked', false);
     } else {
         $(".chk2").prop('checked', false);
     }
 });

 $('.chk').not('[id^=chkAll]').change(function () {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('.chkAll').prop('checked', true);
     } else {
         $('.chkAll').prop('checked', false);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Using same `id` for multiple html elements is not good.. You should be using `class` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {

    function checkAll($all, $els) {
        $all.change(function () {
            $els.prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $els.change(function () {
            $all.prop('checked', $els.not(':checked').length == 0);
        });
    }

    checkAll($('#chkAll'), $('.chk'))
    checkAll($('#chkAll2'), $('.chk2'))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/np4JT/)

Comment: thanks it works :) i have one last question . if  without pay is checked all when i check one of the with pay  the without pay checkall box will be uncheck and the following <td> of without pay

Comment: while uhecking the td("withpay") the checkbox for all for without pay  will be unchecked then the other parallel td will be unxhecked .... sorry for my grammar

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chk-all').on('change', function(){
        $('.' + $(this).data('child')).prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
});
```

for following HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="pay"   class="chk-all" data-child='child-1'/>With Pay</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="pay"  class="chk-all" data-child='child-2'/>Without Pay</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="pay" value="With Pay" class="child-1" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="pay" value="Without Pay" class="child-2"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="pay" value="With Pay" class="child-1" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="pay" value="Without Pay" class="child-2" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zainabed/k7kXf/)